# .bashrc not responding

Tags: command-line, bashrc, prompt

I'm having an odd problem with the `.bashrc` file.

I've added the following line so git could show me the current branch on prompt (I saw this tip [here](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/bashrc))

```
#Show branch in status line
PS1='[\W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ ' export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"'
```

But it doesn't work.
Also, I can't add my own aliases, if I add some to `.bashrc_aliases` it doesn't seem to read them.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to `.bashrc_aliases`, you need to *include* that file in your main `.bashrc` after you create it. You could add the following lines in the end of your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ./.bashrc_aliases ]; then
    . ./.bashrc_aliases
fi
```

After that, you either need to logout and back in again, for the changes to take effect, or you can run `source ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer...

I've already added like you say, and is not working



if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
 . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

Comment: Maybe you have some naming mismatch in your files. In your question you write that you created `.baschr_aliases` (small typo there?) and in your comment above you write that you included `~/.bash_aliases`.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo in here, but in the baschr file is everything fine. I don't know what's the problem

Comment: Well, if you can't get inclusion to work, you can always place the alias commands directly inside `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I've try that too, but is not responding to that either. Any ideas ?